# XAML: Why can't I add a subclass of T to a collection of T?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

**EDIT:** If you're interested, you can clone the source code of the application from GitHub.

https://github.com/jamesqo/Sirloin

Here are the steps to repro:

- `git clone` the URL
- open up the Sirloin.Example project (under src/Sirloin.Example) in VS
- double-click the Package.appxmanifest, go to Packaging, and generate the .pfx file (necessary since it gets gitignored, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303535/should-i-add-my-metro-apps-temporarykey-pfx-file-to-version-control))
- run the project under x86 and you should hit the exception

---

## Original Post

I'm developing an app for Windows 10. I'm running into a problem where, for some reason, I'm unable to add a subclass of `Object` to a collections of objects. Here is the code:

**ObservableList.cs** (basically a wrapper for List which implements `IObservableVector`)

```
public sealed class ObservableList : IObservableVector<object>, IReadOnlyList<object>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";

    // This is non-generic so we can expose it thru the .winmd component
    private readonly List<object> list;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event VectorChangedEventHandler<object> VectorChanged;

    public ObservableList()
    {
        this.list = new List<object>();
    }

    public ObservableList(IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        this.list = new List<object>(items);
    }

    public int Count => list.Count;

    int IReadOnlyCollection<object>.Count => Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set { list[index] = value; }
    }

    object IReadOnlyList<object>.this[int index] => this[index];

    public int IndexOf(object item) => list.IndexOf(item);

    public void Insert(int index, object item)
    {
        list.Insert(index, item);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
        OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
        OnVectorChanged(CollectionChange.ItemInserted, (uint)index);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
        OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
        OnVectorChanged(CollectionChange.ItemRemoved, (uint)index);
    }

    public void Add(object item) =>
        Insert(this.Count, item);

    public void Clear()
    {
        list.Clear();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
        OnVectorChanged(CollectionChange.Reset, 0);
    }

    public bool Contains(object item) => list.Contains(item);

    public void CopyTo(object[] array, int arrayIndex) => 
        list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    public bool Remove(object item)
    {
        int index = this.IndexOf(item);
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        this.RemoveAt(index);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
        OnVectorChanged(CollectionChange.ItemRemoved, (uint)index);
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator() => list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    private void OnVectorChanged(CollectionChange change, uint index)
    {
        VectorChanged?.Invoke(this, new VectorChangedArgs(change, index));
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Relevant portion of **AppView.xaml.cs**:

```
public sealed partial class AppView : UserControl
{
    // Some generic extensions I wrote to minimize boilerplate
    public ObservableList LowerItems =>
        this.GetValue<ObservableList>(LowerItemsProperty);

    public static DependencyProperty LowerItemsProperty { get; } =
        Dependency.Register<ObservableList, AppView>(nameof(LowerItems), LowerItemsPropertyChanged);

    private static void LowerItemsPropertyChanged(AppView o, IPropertyChangedArgs<ObservableList> args)
    {
        var src = args.NewValue;
        var dest = o.lowerView.Items;

        dest.Clear();

        foreach (var item in src) dest.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml** (where I use the AppView)

```
<Page
    x:Class="Sirloin.Example.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="using:Sirloin">

    <s:AppView>
        <!--This is the part that's failing-->
        <s:AppView.LowerItems>
            <s:MenuItem Symbol="Contact"/>
            <s:MenuItem Symbol="Contact"/>
        </s:AppView.LowerItems>
    </s:AppView>
</Page>
```

For some reason, when I run the app, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot add instance of type 'Sirloin.MenuItem' to a collection of type 'Sirloin.ObservableList'.

Seeing is how `ObservableList` is essentially a collection of objects, and of course `MenuItem` is a subclass of `Object`, I don't see why this is the case. Do the types have to exactly match or something?

Unfortunately, I can't use generics here since I'm exposing the first two files as part of a `winmd` component, which (bizarrely) means no public generic types. So I have to make everything that would be generic a collection of objects.

Comment: Just a question, but wouldn't ObservableCollection<T> work just fine? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx  If you want to add sorting and filtering, it works much better to use a CollectionViewSource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Unfortunately, exposing an `ObservableCollection` (even of objects) results in [this error.](http://i.imgur.com/Sg6TvtI.png)

Comment: I don't have a platform I can test UWP right now (I do at home).  In standard WPF it works just fine.  The only lead I can give right now is that the generated code-behind in your `s:AppView.LowerItems` will attempt to replace your default instance of ObservableList with a new one.  Your property change callback is called after the fact.  BTW, your generic extensions are really nice.

Comment: It appears your `LowerItems => GetValue<T>()` call doesn't have a corresponding setter, so it could be erroring out on that.

Comment: I can't see what else could be wrong except your generic extension method for defining dependency properties. Try replacing it with the normal form and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `LowerItems` collection in the *constructor* for it to take in any children.

```
public AppView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += (o, e) => Current = this;
    LowerItems = new ObservableVector();
}
```

Of course by doing this you also need to give `LowerItems` a *setter* (also pointed out by @BerinLoritsch in the *Comment* section).

```
public ObservableVector LowerItems
{
    get { return this.GetValue<ObservableVector>(LowerItemsProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(LowerItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

For testing, I added `ItemsSource="{Binding LowerItems, ElementName=Self}"` to your **lowerView** `ListView` inside your *AppView.xaml* (don't forget to give the `UserControl` an `x:Name="Self"` for the ElementName binding to work).

After these changes you will see the icons appear on the bottom left of the page.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I didn't mark this as the answer because it wasn't the final solution for me. However, it did help me solve the problem, so have an upvote.

Comment: Nws, probably you should consider posting your solution here. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Justin XL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35145064/4077294) wasn't the solution, but it got me thinking. ItemControl's `Items` property only has a getter and not a setter, so how was it able to initialize the property without exposing the setter?

So I took at the look at the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and navigated to `ItemControl.Items`, and it turns out that [it isn't even a dependency property!](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,156) It's just a regular CLR property, which actually makes sense if you think about it, since you wouldn't need to bind to it in XAML if it's readonly.

So basically, all I did was remove the dependency property and `ObservableList` cruft and replace it with this:

```
public ItemCollection LowerItems => lowerView.Items;
public ItemCollection UpperItems => upperView.Items;
```

After that everything worked perfectly.

Comment: There's a good reason that why the Items is a normal CLR readonly property and we just don't use it directly in xaml - It's meant to store *logical* data and you won't be able to define or update the collection via data-binding from your viewmodel. Having said it, if you know you never ever need to change the items defined in xaml, this is fine (unless you go code-behind and do manual update... which is just not mvvm friendly).

Comment: Your solution might be "working", but it is wrong. @JustinXL is correct.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Fair enough. I've accepted his answer.